# ASP.NET App authenticates in Firefox but not in IE

Tags: asp.net, web-config

When I open my ASP.NET app in IE it asks for username and password. I enter them and it rejects them. I do the same in Firefox and it works.

Any ideas? Thanks!

I have `<authentication mode="Windows" />`

Comment: I normally experience this the other way round! Are you specifying a domain e.g. DOMAIN\username?

Comment: Yes. I type the same thing in Firefox and it works..

Comment: How would I allow all in my allow all users in the allow tag in web.config?

Comment: All *authenticated* users? `<allow users="*" />` - anon users would be `<allow users="?" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the Application Pool Identity to Network Service and it worked in both IE and Firefox. Before the Application Pool Identity was a user that was one a different domain than the domain of the user I was trying to login to the App as.